# PHP Pagination target page

Tags: php, pagination

My code is working properly but when i click on the next page in pagination, nothing appear in the page.

I think the problem is the target page

```
       $cat_id = $_GET['cat'];
       $targetpage = "test2.php?cat=$cat_id";
```

Because my [url](http://localhost/shop/test2.php?cat=MOBILE%20PHONES) that I want to have next page is like this

Answer (score 0):

try to encode your url  like bellow

```
$targetpage = "test2.php?cat=".urlencode($_GET['cat']);
```